# how do I stop automysqlbackup throwing LOCK TABLES error?

Tags: 12.04, backup, mysql

How to stop  automysqlbackup's cron.daily script -- as installed and configured from `apt-get install automysqlbackup` -- throwing the following error:

```
 mysqldump: Got error: 1142: SELECT,LOCK TABL command denied to user 
'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' for table 'cond_instances' when using LOCK TABLES
```

This first occurred (for me) after having upgraded to MySQL 5.5 as a consequence of having  upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/automysqlbackup/+bug/995587?comments=all) (which was fixed in `automysqlbackup 2.6+debian.2-1`) can be worked around by stopping automysqlbackup from dumping the `performance_schema` and `information_schema` databases. This can be done by editing `/etc/default/automysqlbackup` as follows:

Add an additional pipe to grep step to remove `performance_schema` and `information_schema` from the list of DBNAMES.

So, in the line that starts `DBNAMES=`, and after `| grep -v ^mysql$` insert

```
| grep -v ^performance_schema$ | grep -v ^information_schema$
```

before `| tr \\\r\\\n ,\` such that the final line should look like

```
DBNAMES=`mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf --execute="SHOW DATABASES" | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v ^Database$ | grep -v ^mysql$ | grep -v ^performance_schema$ | grep -v ^information_schema$ | tr \\\r\\\n ,\ `
```

Thanks to Jérôme Drouet.

Alternatively, if you use the original automysqlbackup package from sourceforge and not the apt-package, you can add the performance_schema database to your excluded databases by modifying the line that contains CONFIG_db_exclude in your /etc/automysqlbackup/myserver.conf:

```
# List of DBNAMES to EXLUCDE if DBNAMES is empty, i.e. ().
CONFIG_db_exclude=( 'information_schema' 'performance_schema' )
```

Comment: Your answer works. Go ahead and select your answer as the correct one.

Comment: This is the fix on OS X (via Homebrew) as well.